# Magento 2 set default weight on admin panel create new product form

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute, products

I am trying to setup default value to weight field to 1 not mater.  it just to prevent virtual product creation.

You can see image below: 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

### set default weight on admin panel create new product form

I a solution working for me, however I would still appreciate to hear your opinion about that it.

Create module

 Create a di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General" type="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General" />
</config>
```

Create a file General.php in this path Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\

i edit only add one line in customizeWeightField function near line ~ 52 
        'value' => (int)$this->locator->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->hasWeight(),

```
<?php
namespace Girit\NoVirtaulProducts\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface;

class General extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General
{

   public function __construct(
      LocatorInterface $locator,
      ArrayManager $arrayManager
  ) {
      parent::__construct($locator, $arrayManager);
  }

protected function customizeWeightField(array $meta)
{
    $weightPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(ProductAttributeInterface::CODE_WEIGHT, $meta, null, 'children');

    if ($weightPath) {
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
            $weightPath . static::META_CONFIG_PATH,
            $meta,
            [
                'dataScope' => ProductAttributeInterface::CODE_WEIGHT,
                'validation' => [
                    'validate-zero-or-greater' => true
                ],
                'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-small',
                'addafter' => $this->locator->getStore()->getConfig('general/locale/weight_unit'),
                'imports' => [
                    'disabled' => '!${$.provider}:' . self::DATA_SCOPE_PRODUCT
                        . '.product_has_weight:value'
                ],
                'value' => (int)$this->locator->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->hasWeight(),
            ]
        );

        $containerPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(
            static::CONTAINER_PREFIX . ProductAttributeInterface::CODE_WEIGHT,
            $meta,
            null,
            'children'
        );
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge($containerPath . static::META_CONFIG_PATH, $meta, [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
        ]);

        $hasWeightPath = $this->arrayManager->slicePath($weightPath, 0, -1) . '/'
            . ProductAttributeInterface::CODE_HAS_WEIGHT;
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->set(
            $hasWeightPath . static::META_CONFIG_PATH,
            $meta,
            [

                'dataType' => 'boolean',
                'formElement' => Form\Element\Select::NAME,
                'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                'dataScope' => 'product_has_weight',
                'label' => '',
                'options' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __('This item has weight'),
                        'value' => 1
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __('This item has no weight'),
                        'value' => 0
                    ],
                ],
                'value' => (int)$this->locator->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->hasWeight(),
            ]
        );
    }

    return $meta;
}
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, your answer save my day.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you want value 1 for weight for all product or just virtual. But you can do this by many ways.

1. You can override product edit admin form file.
2. You can use event/observer to set default value. And make weight not required from db.

let me know if it works.

Comment: my goal is when user click on create new product ( configurable )  , the form  will already with default weight (num)  to prevent virtual product ,  i cant find a way to achieve my goal